# How to add or subtract to, or increment, column letters in Excel? 2nd Part

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have found [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/709086/how-to-add-or-subtract-to-or-increment-column-letters-in-excel) where is answered:

How to add or subtract to, or increment, column letters in Excel?

This time, I want to know how to simplify:

```
=INDIRECT( ADDRESS( ROW()+19, ( COLUMN() - 1 ),4) )
=INDIRECT( ADDRESS( ROW()+19, ( COLUMN() - 3 ),4) )
=INDIRECT( ADDRESS( ROW()+19, ( COLUMN() - 5 ),4) )
```

to:

```
=INDIRECT( ADDRESS( ROW()+19, ( COLUMN() - (2*n-1) ),4) )
```

Comment: What is "n"?.  I don't notice anything obviously wrong with the construction you show (except you need to define n).

Comment: Do you want it to increase as you fill down the formula (1, 3, 5, 7...), or repeat the sequence (1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 5...)?

Comment: At first cell, ... 1 ... . At second cell ....... 3 ...... and so on ... But, I don't want to change the number manually, I just want that the **n** number change itself as I paste from cell to cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give n a value in order to have a working function, you should write instead of n the following:
`Row()`
The Formula will become:
`=INDIRECT( ADDRESS( ROW()+19, ( COLUMN() - (2*(ROW()-4)-1) ),4) )`
the 4 in 2*(ROW()-4)-1) is the row number -1 where you start the formula, I used for example row 5 I have to deduct 1 from it, and it will give 1 after calculation with 2*(ROW()-4)-1) =2*(5-4)-1 =2-1 =1
The formula will become:
`=INDIRECT( ADDRESS( ROW()+19, ( COLUMN() - (2*(ROW()-(Row()-1)-1) ),4) )`  but you have to write the value of Row number -1 , (Row()-1)=4 for example, in that way when you drag down the formula it will deduct always 4 and it means like 1, 3 5...