# MS Excel 2016 - subtract column letter

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have the current formula below in cell A1 where I need to minus/subtract the column letter into a new cell B1. 
I have gone through this post but couldnt work it: 
[How to add or subtract to, or increment, column letters in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/709086/how-to-add-or-subtract-to-or-increment-column-letters-in-excel)

e.g. need formula or macro to create Column B values; which are the same as column A but subtract/minus one column letter

```
    Column A        | Column B  
    =+Jan!$V$36     | =+Jan!$U$36
    =+Jan!$AD$36    | =+Jan!$AC$36
    =+Jan!$AH$36    | =+Jan!$AG$36
```

Comment: You have changed your original question in such a way that my answer is not responsive, so I have deleted it. In the future, if an answer responds to your original question, you should probably just accept it and ask a new question. Otherwise you leave answers in the thread which don't respond to your existing question, and that will be confusing to others searching this forum for answers.

Answer (score 0):

The `+` in your formulas is superfluous and not needed.

Here is a UDF that will place the altered formula in the adjacent column

Assumptions:

- your formulas are simple as you show with only a single cell reference
- The cell reference will always be at the end of the formula.
- The cell reference will always use the absolute addressing mode.
- To make things simpler

  - We use the R1C1 notation in VBA
  - We search from the end of the string in reverse for the `C`
  - This gives us the column number, from which we subtract `1` to get the modified formula.

This should give you enough information that you can change it in case your posted data does not agree with your real data.

*note that when we write it back to the worksheet, it will be converted back to `A1` notation.

```
Option Explicit
Sub prevCol()
    Dim R As Range, C As Range
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim sForm As String
    Dim lColPos As Long, lColNum As Long

Set WS = Worksheets("sheet3") 'or wherever you have the formulas
With WS
    Set R = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

For Each C In R
    If C.HasFormula Then
        sForm = C.FormulaR1C1

        'assuming column number is at the end
        lColPos = InStrRev(sForm, "C")
        lColNum = Mid(sForm, lColPos + 1, 9)
        C.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = Left(sForm, lColPos) & lColNum - 1
    End If
Next C

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: thanks Ron, i have modified question because i have multiple cases with different column letters, so need different formula or macro that has logic to handle that

Comment: @da3data use the same principle as I showed you for the example before you edited your question. Use the COLUMN function to determine the base column. If you can't figure it out, I'll post something in the morning.

Comment: I will work on it now to figure out but please post your ideas asap, thanks